# jsdoc not generating table of contents properly

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jsdoc

I'm running grunt jsdoc module and the output html is missing the filenames in the table of contents.

See image:

[image]

Notice the `js` repeated in right hand column under `modules`

Top of file (AMD):

```
/** @module identity.js
 *
 * abstracts the logic for obtaining a user's identity
 * @module identity.js
 * @type {Core}
*/
```

Comment: [JSDoc is surprisingly frustrating](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/879) when it comes to generating a TOC for the current file, or one that includes all methods of a class. And I haven't yet found an example of how to [document a standard JavaScript module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913504/complete-example-of-jsdoc-documenting-a-javascript-module).